# Connect and retrieve data from Mlab using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, mlab

I'm newbie to MongoDB, so i'm not quiet sure how to do Ajax requests to Mlab... 
I have done    [This](https://plnkr.co/edit/cr4VDR1AZih8WiNxmKg6?p=preview)    for testing purposes and i wish to retrieve the data from Mlab DB,
I guess i need to do something like this

```
// Create MongoDB connection 
var mongo_connect = mongodb://my_username:
my_password@ds66666.mlab.com:59220/my_ebooks

// Create Mongo DB query 
var query_data = db.getCollection('my_ebooks').find({});

$.ajax({
  url: query_data ,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
     format: 'json'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
     // Do something with data
  },     
});
```

Comment: Firstly, passing query_data to a url param is not going to work as the query_data is setting pointer and db.getCollection and not a URL. Ajax call require a url for the call to work. Secondly, db is undefined as you don't have any connection or variable db defined which has connection to the mongoldb. You need to either setup a server side app which has a connection to the DB and then using Ajax make a request to your backend app which would call your mLab db. There is a lot missing to get this solution to work unless there is a js library which you can use to connect to your mongo db.

Comment: Vish - thanks for the quick response, suppose i want to connect to mlab and retrieve data,  by using plunker for testing purposes, is there is a way to do it?

Comment: You won't as you need a server side application layer between your front-end and the DB which will take your front-end request and communicate with the backend.
You're best start would be to look into setting up a server side app to talk to the DB and open an end point to make requests from the front-end. There's also server less concepts which you can explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not going to work like this. The sample you were looking at directly returns some .json. However this data retrieval would typically involve calling some kind of back-end service. Even if it would work from your browser, you wouldn't want that people would see your database credentials in the source code.

Your service would have to run independently from your browser. JavaScript developers would usually use a Node.js, however you would be free to run your back-end with whatever you like e.g. Java, PHP, Python, .net just to name a few. Obviously you would than need a container to run it on. For playing around [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) might be a good start, but you may consider other services like AWS as well.

If you don't want to code your back-end, there are some [REST-API wrappers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) for MongoDB as well. But you will probably need some container/server to run these ones as well.

As Vish already pointed out, you just defined a connection string, but you are never opening up a connection. Without a driver that won't work anyways. You should probably have a look at the [official tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) the one for Node.js is [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/).

Comment: Udo, Vish - Thanks for you response